# java hashtable with a question mark for constructor

Tags: java, hashtable

```
final Hashtable<String, Constructor<?>> constructors =
    new Hashtable<String, Constructor<?>>();
```

can someone please explain what the "Constructor"  does ?

Comment: It defines the value-type of the `HashMap` with an unbound wildcard for `Constructor`'s generic parameter. For more information see [Oracle's tutorial no Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Just to be clear here, `Constructor` has nothing to do with a java class constructor that is used to instantiate objects. Here `Constructor` is a class or an interface.

Comment: thank you  Turing85 &  Joakim Danielson